# Connect Outlets to an Array

Tags: cocoa, macos

Today I was writing a Sudoku Solver and I had everything needed already coded. But now I have a big problem with the UI: How can I connect multiply NSTextFields (81) to an Array inside an object. I already heard about the Array Controller, but I think that isn't the right thing.

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't. Just give them each a unique tag and set their action. The action can use its `sender` parameter to retrieve the tag and figure out which field changed. Or, if you want to find a particular field (say, to set the contents from a saved puzzle), use `-viewWithTag:` to find the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, `viewWithTag` is that what I was looking for. =D